# Cant build project after installing jdk 7

Tags: exception, build, java

After installing jdk 7 and switching java platform for my project in ide i get this when im trying to build project.

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6


An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.tools.javac.util.Name$Table.instance(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/Context;)Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/Name$Table;
    at uk.org.retep.util.javac.JavacUtils.<init>(JavacUtils.java:128)
    at uk.org.retep.util.annotation.AnnotationScannerProcessor.process(AnnotationScannerProcessor.java:76)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1106)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:419)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:333)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:324)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:76)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:61)
```

I know that sun switched some apis or something, but ide doesnt tell me whats wrong exactly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have a complete stack trace. Could you paste fragments of the code?

Comment: Do you use a custom annotation processor? Btw, it tells you what is wrong: the method `com.sun.tools.javac.util.Name$Table.instance(com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context)` is missing. The package might have changed or there might be additional parameters etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really share your code that's causing the exception, but the exception indicates that you're using an internal Java API (any class contained in the `com.sun` packages). You shouldn't be using those APIs directly, as they're considered private implementations and subject to change. As those APIs are private, it isn't as simple as looking for the Javadoc to see what methods are available, but suffice it to say that the method you're calling doesn't exist. You have a few options:

1. If you're calling this method directly, you need to refactor. You should look for ways to accomplish the same work using public APIs.
2. If this happens after calling a library method, you should file a bug with the library maintainer informing them about the error and the risks of using the `com.sun` APIs.
3. If this happens after calling a public Java API (anything in the `java` or `javax` packages) then You should file a bug report with Oracle. This one seems unlikely though.

Also, if you share your code, we may be able to better help you.

[edit]
Further, see [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) for more information about why you shouldn't use classes in the `com.sun` packages.

Comment: thanks for response. Its not the code its when i try to build project. Im using netbeans IDE, which uses ant script

Comment: But, it *IS* the code. Your code doesn't compile because you're calling a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: The problem was in third party library, removed it and project compiled fine. Thanks for help, yock!